# PHP Form Multiple Inputs

Tags: php, html

I am having issues with php and form handling.  I want to be able to click a dropdown box(like you can do with a form in html, with the different options tags) in php, and allow the selection to take the designated value.

Here is what I have :

```
<input value="<?php echo isset($results['example']) ? $results['example']: ''; ?>" class="form-control" name="data[example]" placeholder="Example">
```

That populates with a place you can type in input text, which is accepted perfectly in post, but I do not want the user typing in data, only selecting from options, such as this html form does :

```
<form action="example.php">
<option value="11">apples</option>
<option value="12">bananas</option>
<option value="13">oranges</option>
</form>
```

Here is an edit using the data given :

```
<form>
                            <select name="example">
                                <option value="<?php echo isset($results['example']) ? $results['example']: ''; ?>">apples</option>
                                <option value="<?php echo isset($results['example']) ? $results['example']: ''; ?>">oranges</option>
                                <option value="<?php echo isset($results['example']) ? $results['example']: ''; ?>">bananas</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
```

I did not add the action because it will be posted with other data, but did try both ways(with and without action="post.php") and it does not work...

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Is this a front-end or back-end problem?

Comment: I don't think this question is clear at all.  What happens when you just echo `$results["example"]`?  Your code will currently give you three drop downs with the same value, with just different names for them.  Posting them will always have the result of whatever `$results["example"]` is

Comment: Sorry to be ~that~ guy but I do not believe you have explained what you want very well.

We may be of more help of you could provide more source code or at the very least a var_dump of $_POST, $_GET and $results.

From the code snippets provided by you and various answer you will end up with a drop down whose visible text is apples, oranges, bananas but whose value will all be the same   because they all take it form the same source ($results['example']).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining your options inside a select tag

```
<select>
<option value="11">apples</option>
<option value="12">bananas</option>
<option value="13">oranges</option>
</select>
```

Should give you in your post the position (value) of the selected item. Then in your php pass value to the selected items *11,12,13 = apples,bananas,oranges**

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

You need a `<select name="name"> </select>` around your options

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a dropdown I guess:

```
<form action="example.php">
    <select name="fruit">
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="2">Banana</option>
        <option value="3">Orange</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

On submiting the form you can get the value like: `$_POST['fruit']` (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

**I think you need something like that**

```
<form action="example.php">
    <select name="fruit">
        <option value="<?php echo isset($results['example']) ? $results['example']: ''; ?>">apples</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the issue is not PHP, I think you just need to use the `SELECT` and `OPTION` form tags:

You are specifying an `INPUT` tag, which by definition allows the user to input data.

```
<form action="example.php">
 <select class="form-control" name="data[example]">
    <option value="<?php echo isset($results['example']) ? $results['example']: ''; ?>"">
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use type="checkbox", so you can select one more

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Boat" checked> I have a boat<br>
```

in php

```html
<?php 
$vehicleArray='';
foreach($_POST['vehicle'] as $value) {
  $vehicleArray.=$value.',';
}
//output 'Bike,Car,Boat'
?>
```